# how to find accumulation point of $z_n=e^{in}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

How can I find accumulation point of
 a) $z_n=e^{in} $

b)$z_n=i^n$

c)$z_n=(1-\frac{1}{n})+(-1)^ne^{\frac{1}{n}}i$

I tried at b) $\lim_{n\to\infty}(i^2)^{\frac{n}{2}}=(-1)^{\frac{n}{2}}=-1,+1$

at c) $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-\frac{1}{n})+(-1)^ne^{\frac{1}{n}}i=lim_{n\to\infty}(1)+(-1)^ni=1+i,
1-i$

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) *Hint:* $|e^{in}|=1$, so we have a bounded sequence and ther *must* be at least one acccumulation point; they form a nonempty closed subset of $S^1$. If $z$ is an accumulation point then so is $e^iz$.

In b) you must not replace $i^n$ with $(-1)^{\frac n2}$. Just have a look at the first few terms of the sequence

Your result for c) is correct.

Comment: What is $S^{1}$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

a)

> $$ e^{in}=\cos(n)+i\sin(n). $$

b)

Note that, you can get the accomulation points by seeing that $i^n$ has a period.

Comment: a) is it -1-i and 1+i ?

Comment: Are you really claiming that $i^n = (-1)^n$?

Comment: @mrf: offcourse not. It is corrected.